# How to delay Helm-Charts deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Helm-Chart deployment.yaml uses k8s secrets to mount to a volume. k8s secrets are created after 10mins by executing the helm install. How to delay the deployment when the secrets are created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the secrets don't already exist, you don't need to do anything (other than not use the `helm install --wait` flag); Kubernetes handles this on its own.

When Helm sends the rendered YAML to Kubernetes, it checks that the data matches the schema described in the Kubernetes API, but it does *not* check that any referenced objects (secrets, config maps, PVCs) actually exist.  If they don't yet, the pods will show up as `Pending` in `kubectl get pods` output, and Kubernetes won't actually start the process of starting the pods.  Then later on when you actually install the secrets, Kubernetes on its own will figure out that pod A needed secret B and it's there now, so it can start.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust timeout for deployment. Another option is to set wait flag and wait until the previous deployment is done.
Read [the appropriate documentation part](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-install-upgrade-rollback).